# Ansible set_fact dictionary with nested list

Tags: ansible

I need to be able to convert this:

{
    "529eacea00000003": [

```
    [

        {

            "limitBwInMbps": 0,

            "limitIops": 0,

            "sdcId": "2e18899800000000",

            "sdcIp": "172.21.41.71"

        },

        {

            "limitBwInMbps": 0,

            "limitIops": 0,

            "sdcId": "2e18899900000001",

            "sdcIp": "172.21.41.70"

        },

    ]

],
"529eacea00000002": [

    [

        {

            "limitBwInMbps": 0,

            "limitIops": 0,

            "sdcId": "2e18899800000002",

            "sdcIp": "172.21.41.72"

        },

        {

            "limitBwInMbps": 0,

            "limitIops": 0,

            "sdcId": "2e18899900000003",

            "sdcIp": "172.21.41.73"

        },

    ]

]
```

}

To this:

529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000000
529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000001
529eacea00000002, 2e18899900000002
529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000003

I've tried about every combination of with_items, etc. but no luck

Comment: from where are you getting this map?

Comment: There is a mistake in the 2nd line of the expected result, I think. The last but one element should end with '2' not '3'.

Comment: Actually, there is not the same number of elements in each of the lists. Some have one, some have many. Also, the list, for some reason, did not render correctly. What I needs is this:

Comment: 529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000000 /n
529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000001 /n
529eacea00000002, 2e18899900000002 /n
529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000003 /n

Answer (score 1):

From the part of the data

```
],
"529eacea00000002": [
```

I assume "*this*" are 2 elements of a list. Let's name the list *data1*. Then the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    data2: "{{ data1|
               map('dict2items')|
               list|
               json_query('[].[key,
                               value[0][0].sdcId,
                               key,
                               value[0][1].sdcId]') }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ data2|to_yaml }}"
```

give

```
  msg: |-
    - [529eacea00000003, 2e18899800000000, 529eacea00000003, 2e18899900000001]
    - [529eacea00000002, 2e18899800000002, 529eacea00000002, 2e18899900000003]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      vars:
        vol_list:
          529eace700000000:
            - { sdcId: 2e18b0ae00000005, sdcIp: INVALID }
          529eace800000001:
            - { sdcId: 2e18b0b100000006, sdcIp: 172.21.41.74 }
          529eace900000002:
            - { sdcId: 2e18b0b100000006, sdcIp: 172.21.41.74 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18899c00000004, sdcIp: 172.21.41.67 }
          529eacea00000003:
            - { sdcId: 2e18899800000000, sdcIp: 172.21.41.71 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18899900000001, sdcIp: 172.21.41.70 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18899b00000003, sdcIp: 172.21.41.69 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18899a00000002, sdcIp: 172.21.41.68 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18899c00000004, sdcIp: 172.21.41.67 }
            - { sdcId: 2e18b0b100000006, sdcIp: 172.21.41.74 }
      tasks:
      - debug: var=vol_list

      - set_fact:
          v2s: "{{v2s|default('')}}{% for i in range(0,(vol_list[item])| length) %}{% if i > 0%};{%endif%}{{item}},{{vol_list[item][i].sdcId}}{% if i == (vol_list[item])| length%};{%endif%}{% endfor %};"
        with_items: "{{vol_list}}"

      - set_fact:
          sdc2vol1: "{{ sdc2vol1|default([]) + [ { 'vol': item.split(',')[0], 'sdc': item.split(',')[1]} ] }}"
        with_items: "{{v2s.split(';')}}"
        when: "item | list | length > 0"

      - debug: var=sdc2vol1 

#Yields the following results:
# {
# "sdc2vol1": [
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18b0b100000006",
#         "vol": "529eace800000001"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899800000000",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899900000001",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899b00000003",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899a00000002",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899c00000004",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18b0b100000006",
#         "vol": "529eacea00000003"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18b0b100000006",
#         "vol": "529eace900000002"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18899c00000004",
#         "vol": "529eace900000002"
#     },
#     {
#         "sdc": "2e18b0ae00000005",
#         "vol": "529eace700000000"
#     }
# ]
#}
```